# Jenkins + Webdriver error + chrome +

Tags: selenium, jenkins, webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am using grunt with protractor + selenium. The tests run on MY machine (mac ) perfectly on Chrome and Firefox. But on the CENTOS 6.5 it doesn't run for Chrome. Firefox works on the CENTOS machine. If I remove the Chromedriver from the PATH variable I get the same error. So I know its not the Chromedriver thats causing the issue because I have also specified it in the protractor config file. How do I know if this is a selenium issue or a chromedriver issue? I do an "npm install" and have the "chromedriver": "^2.21.2","protractor": "^3.3.0","selenium-server-standalone-jar": "^2.53.0","webdriver-manager": "^10.0.2"  specified in the package.json. What is the issue while running the grunt command?

The error I get is

```
grunt --ENV=qa --clientName=clientname --device=desktop e2e-test
[4mRunning "protractor:continuous" (protractor) task[24m
[16:00:05] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[16:00:05] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[16:00:06] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at 
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/error.js:27
    super(opt_error);
    ^
WebDriverError: null
    at WebDriverError (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/error.js:27:5)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/error.js:580:13)
    at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:64:13
    at Promise.invokeCallback_ (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1329:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2790:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2773:21)
    at asyncRun (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2652:27)
    at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at acquireSession (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:62:22)
    at Function.createSession (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:295:12)
    at Builder.build (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:458:24)
    at Local.DriverProvider.getNewDriver (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:37:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:182:43)
    at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:255:30
    at _fulfilled (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/q/q.js:604:44
[16:00:27] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
[31m>> [39m/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/error.js:27[31m
>> [39m    super(opt_error);[31m
>> [39m    ^[31m
>> [39mWebDriverError: null[31m
>> [39m    at WebDriverError (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/error.js:27:5)[31m
>> [39m    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/error.js:580:13)[31m
>> [39m    at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:64:13[31m
>> [39m    at Promise.invokeCallback_ (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1329:14)[31m
>> [39m    at TaskQueue.execute_ (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2790:14)[31m
>> [39m    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2773:21)[31m
>> [39m    at asyncRun (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2652:27)[31m
>> [39m    at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7[31m
>> [39m    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)[31m
>> [39mFrom: Task: WebDriver.createSession()[31m
>> [39m    at acquireSession (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:62:22)[31m
>> [39m    at Function.createSession (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:295:12)[31m
>> [39m    at Builder.build (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/builder.js:458:24)[31m
>> [39m    at Local.DriverProvider.getNewDriver (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:37:33)[31m
>> [39m    at Runner.createBrowser (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:182:43)[31m
>> [39m    at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:255:30[31m
>> [39m    at _fulfilled (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)[31m
>> [39m    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)[31m
>> [39m    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)[31m
>> [39m    at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Smoke+Regression tests/node_modules/q/q.js:604:44
[32m>> [39mTest failed but keep the grunt process alive.
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm getting the same error on my Jenkins Protractor tests.

Comment: @JCC I searched for this issue a lot. Although I've not found a solution to this what I've found is anytime when this "super(opt_error)" occurs it seems like the Chromedriver doesn't kick off.Do the following.Upgrade the Java to 1.8 on the server ur running. In my case it was the CENTOS 6.5 machine which unfortunately we could not upgrade due to company policy issues. That being said the workaround I've used is to get it to run on Saucelabs. If your company doesn't have saucelabs creds I seriously would recommend buying. I'll be releasing my project to Github soon. I'll comment here when I do.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get around this error by installing xvfb, the headless driver and then using the same plugin on Jenkins. But now I have other errors that's not this.

Answer (score 0):

Since your server doesn't have a display, you will need to run your tests with xvfb as a virtual display so that the browser window can be rendered.